# Managed Topic Character Limit

Tags: community, community-builder, translation-workbench

How can I increase the character limit of already created Managed Topic in salesforce Community

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no it is a hard limit

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedTopics_static_methods.htm#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20up%20to,maximum%20of%202%2C775%20Navigational%20topics.), You can create up to 25 Featured and 5,000 Content topics. You can create up to eight levels of Navigational managed topics with 25 top-level topics and 10 children topics per level for a maximum of 2,775 Navigational topics.